# navbarPage shiny with two datasets and identical set of widgets - both ways dependence

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I try to create a simple shiny app. What we have here is app with two `tabPanel` modules, each refers to different dataset. Actually both datasets have the same structure (i.e. name of column, name of factors within columns), only difference is column `value` and number of instances in those columns. I would like to create the same layout of each `tabPanel`. I try to depend widget in `Module 1` on widget in `Module 2`. For example, if I choose product `P2` in `Module 1` and then change `tabPanel` into `Module 2`, widget automatically change value into `P2`. The main goal is to create mechanism which allow me to change the value of both widgets in both ways. For example, after I go to the `Module 2` with value `P2` and then I change it into `P3` and come back to `Module 1` I want to see `P3` as well.

**ui.R**

```
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
        navbarPage(title = '',
                   tabPanel("Module 1",
                            fluidRow(
                                    selectInput('prod1','', prod),
                                    ggvisOutput('ggvis_plot1')
                            )
                   ),
                   tabPanel("Module 2",
                            fluidRow(
                                    uiOutput('in_prod2'),
                                    ggvisOutput('ggvis_plot2')
                            ))
        )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        # renderUI part
        output$in_prod2 <- renderUI({
                selectInput('prod2','',
                            choices = prod, selected = input$prod1)
        })

        # Code for data module1
        data_mod1_0 <- reactive({
                df <- module1_df
                df <- df %>% 
                        filter(prod == input$prod1)
        })

        ggvis_plot1 <- reactive({

                plot <- data_mod1_0() %>% 
                        ggvis(~id, ~value) %>% 
                        layer_points(fill = ~part)
        })

        ggvis_plot1 %>% bind_shiny('ggvis_plot1')

        # Code for data module2
        data_mod2_0 <- reactive({
                if (is.null(input$prod2))
                        df <- module2_df
                else {
                        df <- module2_df
                        df <- df %>% 
                                filter(prod == input$prod2)        
                }

        })

        ggvis_plot2 <- reactive({

                plot1 <- data_mod2_0() %>% 
                        ggvis(~id, ~value) %>% 
                        layer_points(fill = ~part)
        })

        ggvis_plot2 %>% bind_shiny('ggvis_plot2')
})
```

**global.R**

```
library(dplyr)

prod <- c('P1','P2','P3')
level <- c('L1','L2','L3')
part <- c('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5')

axis_x <- list(L1 = list('Ordering' = 'id'),
               L2 = list('Ordering' = 'id', 'Part name' = 'part'),
               L3 = list('Ordering' = 'id', 'Part name' = 'part'))

# Data for module 1
set.seed(123)
module1_df <- data.frame(prod = sample(prod,300, replace = T), 
                        level = sample(level, 300, replace = T), 
                        part = sample(part, 300, replace = T),
                        value = rnorm(300))

module1_df <- module1_df %>% 
        group_by(prod) %>% 
        mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
        arrange(prod, id)

# Data for module 2
set.seed(321)
module2_df <- data.frame(prod = sample(prod,300, replace = T), 
                         level = sample(level, 300, replace = T), 
                         part = sample(part, 300, replace = T),
                         value = rnorm(300))

module2_df <- module2_df %>% 
        group_by(prod) %>% 
        mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
        arrange(prod, id)
```

Comment: Can you create the selectInput outside of the two tabPanel() so they can share the input? That is the way I do it to share an input between tabs.

Comment: I know it possible. Though I am interested in this particular goal I presented.

Comment: You could modify your reactive functions to condition upon both prod1 and prod2 input selections. However, which one to condition upon won't be obvious since you don't know which one is the latest explicit user selection. Perhaps you can find a way to track it in another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of this. Basically you use `observeEvent` to determine when a `selectInput` has changed, and then use `updateSelectnput` to update the other select.

```
library(shiny)

ui <-navbarPage(title = '',
                tabPanel("Module 1",
                         fluidRow(
                           selectInput('sel1','Select 1', choices=c("A","B","C")),
                           textOutput('select1')
                         )
                ),
                tabPanel("Module 2",
                         fluidRow(
                           selectInput('sel2','Select 2', choices=c("A","B","C")),
                           textOutput('select2')
                         ))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$select1<-renderText(input$sel1)
  output$select2<-renderText(input$sel2)
  observeEvent(input$sel1, updateSelectInput(session,input='sel2',selected=input$sel1))
  observeEvent(input$sel2, updateSelectInput(session,input='sel1',selected=input$sel2))
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```