# Update selectInput on change of another selectInput 2 ways vice versa

Tags: r, shiny

I need to change the value of one selectInput, with its own input id, whenever the value of another selectInput, with a different input id changes and vice-versa.

My current problem is that my solution works only one way, I would like it to works 2 ways. When the second selectInput is correctly updated by the change on the first selectInput, the dropdown menu of the second doesn't show the full list of one field of refBase anymore.

Here is the code I'm currently using :

```
observe({
  choice <- refBase[match(input$in3, refBase[, 3]), 1]
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "in4", choices = choice, server = FALSE)
})
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34652284/2679518) what you need?

Comment: it works! Thank you `observeEvent(input$in3, updateSelectInput(session, input = 'in4', selected=refBase[match(input$in3, refBase[, 3]), 1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
observeEvent(input$in3, updateSelectInput(session, input = 'in4', selected=refBase[match(input$in3, refBase[, 3]), 1]))
observeEvent(input$in4, updateSelectInput(session, input = 'in3', selected=refBase[match(input$in4, refBase[, 1]), 3]))
```